# How does the Solidity compiler translate the `using .. for` statement?

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to figure out how `using [Library] for [type]` is compiled by the solc compiler.  I noticed that address placeholders are not in the bytecode as with other library references.  So what exactly does the compiler do here?

I understand [from the documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.2/contracts.html#using-for), that it 'attaches' the functions to a type, but does that mean it takes the relevant library code and adds it to the compiled bytecode?

Comment: I believe it depends on the functions in the library. Pure functions are just inlined (so yes, included with your compiled bytecode).

Comment: That's an interesting question. When debugging in Remix the Set.Data example from https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.2/contracts.html#using-for there is a DELEGATECALL to the library for the insert function. What I didn't get yet: at which point is he deploying and linking the library contract? In the init code of C?